# Unable to inline elements in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inline, bootstrap-5

I want some elements to be in one line, here's my html code:

```css
h2 {
  color: Red;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
}

h2.class1 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2.class2 {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</html>

<!-- Code -->
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container-sm center" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50px" height="50px" style="border-radius:25px;">
      <h2 style="font-size: 25px;">Some Heading Text</h2>
      <h2 class="class1">{}></h2>
      <h2 class="class2"> Some Tagline Like Text</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what is the resulting output:
[image: output].

Also, Here's how i want it to look like (this is after removing bootstrap):
[image: expected output]

Edit: Things I tried:-

- d-inline-block
- inline-block
- float property
- experimenting with margins
- Some Bootstrap Classes(sorry i forgot which)
- Code Blocks I got from stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try out the code below I have made some big changes with your markup as well as Css**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      h2 {
        color: Red;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        
      }

     
      h2.class1 {
        color: green;
        font-size: 20px;
        
      }

      h2.class2 {
        color: yellow;
        font-size: 14px;
        
      }

      .bg {
        background-color: black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bg-dark">
      <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"
        width="50px"
        height="50px"
        style="border-radius: 25px"
      />
      <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline my-4">
        <h2 style="font-size: 25px">Some Heading Text</h2>
        <h2 class="class1">{}></h2>
        <h2 class="class2">Some Tagline Like Text</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't forget to add bootstrap starter files such as stylesheet and script

Comment: I hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice, But same like the above one. isn't there a way to keep things at ground level and just send the element at top?

Comment: What do you mean by things at ground level please explain it more ?

Comment: watch my example image, on how i want things to work. There you'll find that my elements stay down and this is not that, it sends things upwards

Comment: For instance compare https://ibb.co/7bncWPb (your code) by this:
https://ibb.co/4Sykvw3 (my example)

Comment: Okay I found your problem!

Comment: @BlindSpot I have made some changes try out the code again and let me know.

Comment: @BlindSpot I think this time I could solve your problem Thankyou!!

Comment: oh so you used "align-self-end my-4". Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Thanks for helping but there's still a problem and it isn't fully resolved, as you see i have used center class  to center my elements but it's all on left, I observed that it was getiing created becoz of my-4 class

Comment: @BlindSpot I have made some extra changes to align it left and make your code quality better but if you still want to center your content replace justify-content-start to justify-content-center in markup which I have used.

Comment: I hope this time your problem will get solved Thankyou!!

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any "justify-content-start" class?

Comment: @BlindSpot justify-content-start is my bootstrap class which I have used directly in markup see inside markup once.

Comment: Ah ok got it, sorry it was maybe a stackoverflow lag

Comment: After a lot of discussions finally, I hope you are satisfied!

Comment: yes lol thanks for helping, i have already ticked it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
use d-inline-flex instead d-grid

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>



</html>

<!-- Code -->
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container-sm center" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div class="d-inline-flex col-12 ">
      <img  src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50px" height="50px" style="border-radius:25px;">
      <h2  style="font-size: 25px;">Some Heading Text</h2>
      <h2 class="class1">{}></h2>
      <h2 class="class2"> Some Tagline Like Text</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sends "everything" upwards, probably not a best solution.

Comment: removed your classes?

Comment: you mean div classes?